# Querying for NaN and other names in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have a dataframe `df` with a column `value` holding some float values and some `NaN`. How can I get the part of the dataframe where we have `NaN` **using the query syntax**?

The following, for example, does not work:

```
df.query( '(value < 10) or (value == NaN)' )
```

I get `name NaN is not defined` (same for `df.query('value ==NaN')`)

Generally speaking, is there any way to use numpy names in query, such as `inf`, `nan`, `pi`, `e`, etc.?

Answer (score 118, accepted):

In general, you could use `@local_variable_name`, so something like

```
>>> pi = np.pi; nan = np.nan
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"value": [3,4,9,10,11,np.nan,12]})
>>> df.query("(value < 10) and (value > @pi)")
   value
1      4
2      9
```

would work, but `nan` isn't equal to itself, so `value == NaN` will always be false.  One way to hack around this is to use that fact, and use `value != value` as an `isnan` check.  We have

```
>>> df.query("(value < 10) or (value == @nan)")
   value
0      3
1      4
2      9
```

but

```
>>> df.query("(value < 10) or (value != value)")
   value
0      3
1      4
2      9
5    NaN
```

Comment: There should be a better way of doing this... but I like the hack.

Comment: The `@nan` "trick"  is *not* working for `numpy` vars e.g.  `nan = numpy.nan`. It *does* work to filter out other *string*'s .

Comment: @javadba: er, the whole point of that section is to show that `(value == @nan)` _doesn't_ work, because nan isn't equal to itself, hence my use of the `value != value` trick.

Comment: Ok I see that now.  Setting `value == value` then works for *excluding* NaN's

Comment: Warning: this does not work with pd.NA entries (pandas version 1.0.3).

Answer (score 140):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46021212/18891) you can use:

```
df.query('value < 10 | value.isnull()', engine='python')
```

I verified that it works.

Comment: `engine='python'` is not even necessary in this case

Comment: @JakubKukul it depends on the dtype of the column. For floats, that have native NaNs, it is not necessary, but if the column are strings or ints, you do.

Comment: What is engine = 'python' doing in the script?

Comment: It interprets the expression as a Python expression instead of a pandas expression (numexpr). https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.eval.html#pandas.eval

Answer (score 54):

You can use the [`isna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isna.html#pandas.Series.isna) and [`notna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.notna.html#pandas.Series.notna) `Series` methods, which is concise and readable.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'value': [3, 4, 9, 10, 11, np.nan, 12]})
available = df.query("value.notna()")
print(available)

#    value
# 0    3.0
# 1    4.0
# 2    9.0
# 3   10.0
# 4   11.0
# 6   12.0

not_available = df.query("value.isna()")
print(not_available)

#    value
# 5    NaN
```

In case you have [`numexpr`](https://pypi.org/project/numexpr/) installed, you need to pass `engine="python"` to make it work with `.query`.
`numexpr` is [recommended](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/enhancingperf.html#expression-evaluation-via-eval) by pandas to speed up the performance of `.query` on larger datasets.

```py
available = df.query("value.notna()", engine="python")
print(available)
```

Alternatively, you can use the toplevel [`pd.isna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isna.html) function, by referencing it as a local variable. Again, passing `engine="python"` is required when `numexpr` is present.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


df = pd.DataFrame({'value': [3, 4, 9, 10, 11, np.nan, 12]})
df.query("@pd.isna(value)")

#    value
# 5    NaN
```

Comment: Your first example returns `*** TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed` on Pandas 1.2.1

Comment: @Keto thanks for the catch! I updated the answer to address this behavior.

Comment: I think this the correct answer - hack is cool though!

Answer (score 41):

For rows where `value` is not null

```
df.query("value == value")
```

For rows where `value` is null

```
df.query("value != value")
```

Comment: Nice! I believe this is what the post author wanted.

Comment: Any explanation of how this is working ??? Kinda curious.

Comment: @DipanwitaMallick in pandas/numpy NaN != NaN. So NaN is not equal itself.

Comment: @DipanwitaMallick my comment is maybe a bit too short. In pandas/numpy NaN != NaN. So NaN is not equal itself. So to check if a cell has a NaN value you can check for cell_value != cell_value -> that is only true for NaNs (3 != 3 is False but NaN != NaN is True and that query only returns the ones with True -> the NaNs). To check if a cell has not a NaN you check for cell_value == cell_value -> that is only true for not NaNs (3 == 3 is True but NaN == NaN is False and that query returns only the ones with True -> not NaNs).

Answer (score 12):

Pandas fills empty cells in a DataFrame with NumPy's nan values. As it turns out, this has some funny properties. For one, *nothing* is equal to this kind of null, even itself. As a result, you can't search for it by checking for any particular equality.

```
In : 'nan' == np.nan
Out: False

In : None == np.nan
Out: False

In : np.nan == np.nan
Out: False
```

However, because a cell containing a np.nan value will not be equal to *anything, including another np.nan value,* we can check to see if it is unequal to itself.

```
In : np.nan != np.nan
Out: True
```

You can take advantage of this using Pandas query method by simply searching for cells where the value in a particular column is unequal to itself.

```
df.query('a != a')
```

or

```
df[df['a'] != df['a']]
```

Comment: This solved my problem, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This should also work: `df.query("value == 'NaN'")`

Comment: Isn't that a string comparison? What if `value` is a float? It is not working for me to for numerical columns.

Answer (score -1):

I think other answers will normally be better.  In one case, my query had to go through eval (use eval very carefully) and the syntax below was useful.  Requiring a number to be both less than and greater than or equal to excludes all numbers, leaving only null-like values.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'value':[3,4,9,10,11,np.nan, 12]})

df.query("value < 10 or (~(value < 10) and ~(value >= 10))")
```

Comment: Code-only answers are considered low quality: make sure to provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post. See [Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/)