# Boolean Series key will be reindexed to match DataFrame index

Tags: python, pandas

Here is how I encountered the warning:

```
df.loc[a_list][df.a_col.isnull()]
```

The type of `a_list` is `Int64Index`， it contains a list of row indexes. All of these row indexes belong to `df`.

The `df.a_col.isnull()` part is a condition I need for filtering.

If I execute the following commands individually, I do not get any warnings:

```
df.loc[a_list]
df[df.a_col.isnull()]
```

But if I put them together `df.loc[a_list][df.a_col.isnull()]`, I get the warning message (but I can see the result):

> Boolean Series key will be reindexed to match DataFrame index

What is the meaning of this warning message? Does it affect the result that it returned?

Answer (score 127, accepted):

Your approach will work despite the warning, but it's best not to rely on implicit, unclear behavior.

**Solution 1**, make the selection of indices in `a_list` a boolean mask:

```
df[df.index.isin(a_list) & df.a_col.isnull()]
```

**Solution 2**, do it in two steps:

```
df2 = df.loc[a_list]
df2[df2.a_col.isnull()]
```

**Solution 3**, if you want a one-liner, use a trick found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26535881/5276797):

```
df.loc[a_list].query('a_col != a_col')
```

---

The warning comes from the fact that the boolean vector `df.a_col.isnull()` is the length of `df`, while `df.loc[a_list]` is of the length of `a_list`, i.e. shorter. Therefore, some indices in `df.a_col.isnull()` are not in `df.loc[a_list]`.

What pandas does is reindex the boolean series on the index of the calling dataframe. In effect, it gets from `df.a_col.isnull()` the values corresponding to the indices in `a_list`. This works, but the behavior is implicit, and could easily change in the future, so that's what the warning is about.

Comment: In pandas 1.4.3, Solution 1 still has the warning.

Answer (score 22):

If you got this warning, using `.loc[]` instead of `[]` suppresses this warning.<sup>1</sup>

```py
df.loc[boolean_mask]           # <--------- OK
df[boolean_mask]               # <--------- warning
```

For the particular case in the OP, you can chain `.loc[]` indexers:

```py
df.loc[a_list].loc[df['a_col'].isna()]
```

or chain all conditions using `and` inside `query()`:

```py
# if a_list is a list of indices of df
df.query("index in @a_list and a_col != a_col")

# if a_list is a list of values in some other column such as b_col
df.query("b_col in @a_list and a_col != a_col")
```

or chain all conditions using `&` inside `[]` (as in @IanS's post).

---

This warning occurs if

- the index of the boolean mask is **not in the same order** as the index of the dataframe it is filtering.

  ```py
  df = pd.DataFrame({'a_col':[1, 2, np.nan]}, index=[0, 1, 2])
  m1 = pd.Series([True, False, True], index=[2, 1, 0])
  df.loc[m1]       # <--------- OK
  df[m1]           # <--------- warning
  ```
- the index of a boolean mask is a **super set** of the index of the dataframe it is filtering. For example:

  ```py
  m2 = pd.Series([True, False, True, True], np.r_[df.index, 10])
  df.loc[m2]       # <--------- OK
  df[m2]           # <--------- warning
  ```

---

<sup>1: If we look at the source codes of [`[]`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/main/pandas/core/frame.py) and [`loc[]`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/main/pandas/core/indexing.py), literally the only difference when the index of the boolean mask is a (weak) super set of the index of the dataframe is that `[]` shows this warning (via `_getitem_bool_array` method) and `loc[]` does not.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

First of all, a warning is not an error. Pandas is simply informing you that it needs to reindex the boolean mask to perform this task, ensuring that the mask has an identical index as the target frame. I don't know why this warning will not be shown if you use `loc` or `query`, but I think Pandas uses reindexing in those cases as well. To avoid this warning, you can manually reindex your boolean mask (which Pandas does automatically for you) before applying it:

```
df[boolean_mask.reindex_like(df)]

df[boolen_mask.reindex(df.index)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Coming across this page, I received the same error by querying the full dataframe, but using the results against sub data.

Create a subset of data and store in variable `sub_df`:

```
sub_df = df[df['a'] == 1]
sub_df = sub_df[df['b'] == 1] # Note "df" hiding here
```

Solution:

Be sure to use the same dataframe each time (in my case, only `sub_df`):

```
# Last line should instead be:
sub_df = sub_df[sub_df['b'] == 1]
```