# UserWarning: Boolean Series key will be reindexed to match DataFrame index

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, user-warning

When using this statement this shows multiple warning in a single statements:

```
Internaldfdeny=pd.DataFrame({'Count':Internaldf[Internaldf['Status']=='deny'][Internaldf['SrcIP']!="NA"][Internaldf['DstIP']!="NA"][Internaldf['TimeStamp']-Internaldf['TimeStamp'].iloc[0]<pd.tslib.Timedelta(minutes=30)].groupby(['DstPort','SrcIP']).size()}).reset_index().pivot_table('Count',['DstPort'],'SrcIP').fillna(0).to_sparse(fill_value=0)
```

the warning comes out to be:

> /home/lubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:1:
>   UserWarning: Boolean Series key will be reindexed to match DataFrame
>   index.
>         """Entry point for launching an IPython kernel.
>       /home/lubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:1:
>   UserWarning: Boolean Series key will be reindexed to match DataFrame
>   index.
>         """Entry point for launching an IPython kernel.
>       /home/lubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:1:
>   FutureWarning: pandas.tslib is deprecated and will be removed in a
>   future version.
>       You can access Timedelta as pandas.Timedelta
>         """Entry point for launching an IPython kernel.
>       /home/lubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:1:
>   UserWarning: Boolean Series key will be reindexed to match DataFrame
>   index.
>         """Entry point for launching an IPython kernel.

I couldn't find any other method of pivoting the table:

I had checked without to_sparse(0) but it still shows it! 
Is this an important warning?
I have been neglecting it.
I've been using
Jupyter Notebook 
Python v3.6
Installed through anaconda if that at all is relevant.

Edit:

```
Internaldf.head()
```

shows

```
                   TimeStamp          SrcIP          DstIP  DstPort Status
0 2018-03-31 03:48:13.731929  192.168.52.43  166.62.28.228       80  close
1 2018-03-31 03:48:13.749007  10.208.23.136    96.45.33.73     8888   deny
2 2018-03-31 03:48:13.799235    10.208.2.56   14.142.64.16     8081   deny
3 2018-03-31 03:48:13.799235  10.208.35.193  13.75.119.102      443  close
4 2018-03-31 03:48:13.799235    10.208.2.70   10.208.3.255      137   deny
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe need:

```
m1 = Internaldf['Status']=='deny'
m2 = Internaldf['SrcIP']!="NA"
#if want check non NaNs
#m2 = Internaldf['SrcIP'].notnull()
m3 = Internaldf['DstIP']!="NA"
#if want check non NaNs
#m3 = Internaldf['DstIP'].notnull()
m4 = Internaldf['TimeStamp']-Internaldf['TimeStamp'].iloc[0] < pd.Timedelta(minutes=30)

#chain condition with & for AND or by | for OR, for column use reset_index 
df=Internaldf[m1 & m2 & m3 & m4].groupby(['DstPort','SrcIP']).size().reset_index(name='Count')

Internaldfdeny=df.pivot_table('Count','DstPort','SrcIP').fillna(0).to_sparse(fill_value=0)
print (Internaldfdeny)
SrcIP    10.208.2.56  10.208.2.70  10.208.23.136
DstPort                                         
137              0.0          1.0            0.0
8081             1.0          0.0            0.0
8888             0.0          0.0            1.0
```

Comment: i still did not understand why it is giving the warning

Comment: @HarshSharma - I have no your sample data, but guess problem is with `DataFrame` constructor

Comment: i've added the table, sorry for unable to directly add the table

Comment: @HarshSharma - No problem, already change it. How working my solution?

Comment: @HarshSharma - I test your original solution and poblem is with filtering `Internaldf[Internaldf['Status']=='deny'][Internaldf['SrcIP']!="NA"][Internaldf['DstIP']!="NA"][Internaldf['TimeStamp']-Internaldf['TimeStamp'].iloc[0]<pd.tslib.Timedelta(minutes=30)]`, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41710789) for more info

Comment: The Internaldf.query() method works thanks for referring it