# How to avoid UserWarning: Boolean Series key will be reindexed to match DataFrame index?

Tags: python, pandas, ipython

My input:

```
df.query('date == 2009')[df['id'] == 35988].index[0]
```

The error raised:

> C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py:1: UserWarning: Boolean Series key will be reindexed to match DataFrame index.
>         "Entry point for launching an IPython kernel.

The output:

```
11136
```

How to avoid an error, keeping given output?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51055788/userwarning-boolean-series-key-will-be-reindexed-to-match-dataframe-index

Answer (score 1):

Without example data, I can't test these potential solutions, but maybe one or both will work for you.

Option 1: include both conditions in `DatFrame.query`:

```
df.query('date == 2009 & id == 35988').index[0]
```

Option 2: reverse the order of the two queries with something like this:

```
df[df['id'] == 35988].query('date == 2009').index[0]
```

Comment: Thank you, Peter. I already found the second option... let me check the first one ))

Comment: FIrst one is not works, due different data types in 'date' and 'id'

Comment: Interesting. What are the data types of `date` and `id`? Not both integers?

Comment: date - int, id - int

Comment: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'str' and 'str'

Comment: interesting... both don't work in 'for loop', where values are changed to variables.. trying to find a way to use .loc instead .query