# Boolean Key Reindexed on isnull().any(axis=1)

Tags: python, pandas

I've seen the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41710789/2193381) and [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41715287/2193381) relating to the User Warning: Boolean Series key will be reindexed to match DataFrame index

I've tried breaking out the commands individually as best I could but still get the UserWarning. What else could I do to make the below more explicit than it already is, and eliminate the warning on the last two statements (`dfa_ = dfa[qux]` and `dfb_ = dfb[qux]`)?

```
import random
import pandas as pd

fields = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']

def randstring(x=3):
    return ''.join([chr(random.randrange(65, 91)) for _ in range(x)])

def randstrlist(x=3):
    return [randstring(x) for _ in range(5)]

values = {field: randstrlist() for field in fields}

def getitem():
    return {field: random.choice(values[field]) for field in fields}

def getdata(setsize=100):
    return [getitem() for _ in range(setsize)]

dfa = getdata()
dfb = getdata()

cols = dfa.columns.tolist()
dfa['qux'] = dfa.groupby(cols).cumcount()
dfb['qux'] = dfb.groupby(cols).cumcount()
cols = cols + ['qux']

dfo = pd.merge(dfa, dfb, on=cols, how='outer').drop('qux', 1)
qux = dfo.isnull().any(axis=1)
dfa_ = dfa[qux]
dfb_ = dfb[qux]
```

Comment: Can you please provide a [MCVE]?

Comment: Added a minimal, complete, and verifiable example. Cheers.

Comment: I solved the actual problem of finding items in `dfa not in dfb` and in `dfb not in dfa` by using `indicator=True` in my `outer` `pd.merge`, and then doing `qux = dfo['_merge'] == 'left_only'` following by `dfo[qux]` which is explicit and does not give me the same warning. My interest in understanding the right way to resolve this UserWarning has not waned.