# pandas check if column is null with query function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, null

I have pandas dataframe that I want to execute on it query function with isnull() or not isnull() condition like that:

```
In [67]: df_data = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,20,None,40,50]})
In [68]: df_data
Out[68]:       a
         0   1.0
         1  20.0
         2   NaN
         3  40.0
         4  50.0
```

if I use this command:

```
df_data.query('a isnull', engine='python')
```

or this command:

```
df_data.query('a isnull()', engine='python')
```

I get an error:

```
In [75]: df_data.query('a isnull', engine='python')  
File "<unknown>", line 1    a isnull           
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

In [76]: df_data.query('a isnull()', engine='python')  
File "<unknown>", line 1    a isnull ()           
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What is the right way to do that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Use `.`:

```
a = df_data.query('a.isnull()', engine='python')
print (a)
    a
2 NaN

b = df_data.query('a.notnull()', engine='python')
print (b)
      a
0   1.0
1  20.0
3  40.0
4  50.0
```

---

You can use also logic `NaN != NaN`:

```
a = df_data.query('a != a')
print (a)
    a
 2 NaN

b = df_data.query('a == a')
print (b)
      a
0   1.0
1  20.0
3  40.0
4  50.0
```

Comment: `df_data.query('a.isnull()')` works without engine='python'

Comment: I can't get this to work without the engine='python'

Comment: I don't think `df_data.query('a.isnull()')` works in Pandas 1.x, not sure what broke it.

Comment: I really like the `a == a` trick