# extract rows which contain only NaN and 0

Tags: python, pandas, nan, sklearn-pandas

I have a dataframe which contains NaNs and 0s in some rows for all columns. I am trying to extract such rows, so that I can process them further. Also, some of these columns are object and some float. I am trying the below code to extract such rows, but because of the columns being object, its not giving me the desired result.

Now, I can solve this problem by substituting some arbitrary values to NaN and use it in .isin statement, but then it also changes the datatype of my columns, and I would have to convert them back.

Can somebody please help me with a workaround/solution to this.
Thanks.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[np.nan,0,np.nan,1,'abc'], 'b':[0,np.nan,np.nan,1,np.nan]})

df

     a   b
0   NaN 0.0
1   0   NaN
2   NaN NaN
3   1   1.0
4   abc NaN
5   NaN 1.0

values = [np.nan,0]
df_all_empty = df[df.isin(values).all(1)]
df_all_empty
```

Expected Output:

```
     a   b
0   NaN 0.0
1   0   NaN
2   NaN NaN
```

Actual Output:

```
     a  b
0   NaN 0.0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
df_all_empty = df[(df.isnull()|df.isin([0])).all(1)]
```

Comment: The `df.isin(values)` matrix for this dataframe is 
[ 0   True   True,  1   True  False , 2   True  False, 3  False  False,  4  False  False ]

Do you have any why? 

I couldnt see why the value in 1,b is False, so I assumed something with the comparison to NaNs using `isin` is wrong

Comment: Looks like `np.NaN != np.NaN` in numpy. So better to use `df[(df.isnull()|df.isin([0])).all(1)]`

Answer (score 0):

The code below will let you select those rows.

```
df_sel = df.loc[(df.a.isnull()) | \
                (df.b.isnull()) | \
                (df.a==0)       | \
                (df.b==0)           ]
```

If you want to make column 'a' in those rows, say for example -9999, you can use:

```
df.loc[(df.a.isnull()) | \
       (df.b.isnull()) | \
       (df.a==0)       | \
       (df.b==0)           , 'a'] = -9999
```

For reference, refer to the official documentation, in

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing

Answer (score 0):

You can use `df.query`, and the trick described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26535563/querying-for-nan-and-other-names-in-pandas) (compare to NaN by checking if a value equals to itself)

Write something like this:

```
df.query("(a!=a or a==0) and (b!=b or b==0)")
```

And the output is:

```
     a    b
0  NaN  0.0
1    0  NaN
2  NaN  NaN
```