# How to separate numerical from nan values?

Tags: python, pandas

I have pandas data frame with a lot of missing data.If I go for

```
d = dfs['REV_PIZ'].isna()
```

Output is boolean.

```
0        True
1        True
2        True
3        True
4        True
5        True
6        True
7        True
```

What I really want is to have d only with numerical values, that would enable me to further maths on this column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is unclear if there are non numeric values, so 2 possible solutions:

---

If all values are numeric is possible use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`isna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isna.html):

```
d = dfs[dfs['REV_PIZ'].notna()]
```

Or [`dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) by column `REV_PIZ`:

```
d = dfs.dropna(subset=['REV_PIZ'])
```

**Sample**:

```
dfs = pd.DataFrame({'REV_PIZ':[1,2,np.nan]})
d = dfs.dropna(subset=['REV_PIZ'])
print (d)
   REV_PIZ
0      1.0
1      2.0
```

---

If mixed numeric with non numeric add [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html) with `errors='coerce'` for convert non numeric to `NaN`s:

```
dfs = pd.DataFrame({'REV_PIZ':[1,2,np.nan,'a']})
dfs['REV_PIZ'] = pd.to_numeric(dfs['REV_PIZ'], errors='coerce')
d = dfs.dropna(subset=['REV_PIZ'])
print (d)
   REV_PIZ
0      1.0
1      2.0
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your question almost answers itself, you could just filter them out like

`d = dfs[~dfs['REV_PIZ'].isna()]`

Answer (score 0):

This should work-

```
d=dfs.query("REV_PIZ==REV_PIZ")
```

see here- [Querying for NaN and other names in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26535563/querying-for-nan-and-other-names-in-pandas)

Comment: I got AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'query'

Comment: You said `dfs` was a Dataframe, not a series