# How to insert an isna() clause in a Pandas query

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I would like to create an isna() clause using the .query() method in Pandas

I am getting an error though.

For a reproducible example:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

mpg = sns.load_dataset('mpg')

mpg[mpg['cylinders'].isna()] # This works

mpg.query('cylinders.isna()') # This raises an exception
TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed
```

Comment: What's the exception?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Querying for NaN and other names in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26535563/querying-for-nan-and-other-names-in-pandas)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use parameter `engine='python'` for change default `engine='numexpr'`:

```
print(mpg.query('cylinders.isna()', engine='python'))
```

**Sample**:

```
mpg = pd.DataFrame({'cylinders':['a', np.nan]})
print(mpg)
  cylinders
0         a
1       NaN

print(mpg.query('cylinders.isna()', engine='python'))
  cylinders
1       NaN
```

More information about `query` is in [Dynamic Expression Evaluation in pandas using pd.eval()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53779987/2901002).