# Python pandas select condition why to write dataframe name twice like frame[frame['col1'].notna()]?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have more experience with `SQL` then with `Python` and now start to use `Python` more. I've read [comparison with sql](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/comparison/comparison_with_sql.html) for `pandas`.

`Groupby` is clear to understand for me `groupby('colname')`.

However why for `select` we need to write name of frame twice like in example `frame[frame['col1'].notna()]` I could not find a reason via web search.

Comment: This is called boolean masking, and is a way to select subsets of your data. See [the indexing docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing)

Comment: I suggest you run it step by step. `DataFrame.notna()` creates logical arrays(df) that you then use for subsetting.

Comment: It is a python convention for numpy and pandas (which is built on numpy), as in the link I posted it's also called boolean indexing, and you can also use the pandas `mask()` function to achieve the same result

Comment: @NelsonGon, I did that, I just could not get how array of `True` could be useful for _getitem_ as there were no such (`True`) items in my frame. With G. Anderson remarks I see now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just summarizing helpful comments:

This is called [boolean masking/indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing), and is a way to select subsets of your data. It is a *Python* convention for *numpy* and *pandas* (which is built on *numpy*), *pandas* `mask()` function can be used to achieve the same result.

Comment: also related use of bitwise `&` `|` not Pythons's `and` `or` in pandas https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21415661/logical-operators-for-boolean-indexing-in-pandas

Answer (score 0):

Just to add, nowadays you can use the `query` method to achieve a somewhat more natural SQL-like syntax, see e.g. [Querying for NaN and other names in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26535563/querying-for-nan-and-other-names-in-pandas)